# ttest_ind returning nan from arrays of different lengths

Tags: pandas, scipy, t-test

I have this dataframe in pandas

```
passes:
        euc_dist  abs_time time_bin
100329      16.0      79.0     0-15
100466      20.0     575.0     0-15
100512      56.0     729.0     0-15
100637      48.0    1314.0    15-30
100744      62.0    1791.0    15-30
100796      62.0    1962.0    30-45
100816      52.0    2384.0    30-45
100972      41.0    2749.0    45-60
101025      41.0    2908.0    45-60
101188      58.0    3439.0    45-60
101401      52.0    4285.0    60-75
101419      60.0    4427.0    60-75
101569      39.0    5003.0    75-90
101636      79.0    5243.0    75-90
```

These are soccer goalkeeper passes for reference. I am attempting to run a t-test on euc_dist and abs_time grouped by time_bin. Often times, the bin arrays are different in size. For example:

```
print(f"bin a:\n{bin_a}") 
print(f"bin b:\n{bin_b}") 
rv = scipy.stats.ttest_ind(bin_a, bin_b, nan_policy="propagate")[1]
print(f"p-value from {period1} and {period2}: {rv}")


bin a:
100329    16.0
100466    20.0
100512    56.0
Name: euc_dist, dtype: float64
bin b:
100637    48.0
100744    62.0
Name: euc_dist, dtype: float64
p-value from 0-15 and 15-30: 0.25271833635089846
```

In this case, I still received a p-value back. However, when I try another game and try to run these bins, I receive a nan:

```
bin a:
95150    33.0
95282    43.0
95409    48.0
Name: euc_dist, dtype: float64
bin b:
95557    56.0
Name: euc_dist, dtype: float64
p-value from 0-15 and 15-30: nan
was running t-test on 0-15 and 15-30 for game2058014
```

Could this resulting nan occur due to the differing sizes of the bins? I'm a comp sci student trying to learn statistics through this research project, please forgive my naivety.

I was expecting to get a non-nan value back from that as well. I looked into equal variance and googled to see if I should be setting equal_var=True in the t-test args, but if this test simply compares the means of two samples, what difference should the sample size make? The 'alternative' arg seems promising but I'm not sure how to interpret it.

Answer (score 0):

Try a t-test where, a single value is compared against the mean value of the sample [your 2nd example contains a single value in "bin b"], rather than comparing mean_of_sample vs mean_of_sample (I don't have enough reputation to write this as a comment).
For example:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_1samp.html